# Occur with many conditions?

Tags: occur

If I want to show only lines that content `"Buy"` I use command `occur`:

Like this:
[image]

[image]

Nice.

But I need to show lines that content `"Buy"` **and** `0.00000057`

So the result must like this
[image]

How I can do this by `occur` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that `BUY` always comes before `0.00000057`, you can give `occur` the regex `BUY.*0.00000057`.

That will search for all lines that have `BUY`, any number of characters, then `0.00000057` in it.

#### Alternate package

If you use [helm swoop](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/helm-swoop), not only can you specify them in either order (swooping for `BUY 0.00000057` is the same as `0.00000057 BUY`), but you also get live results, and easier navigation between them.

Answer (score 7):

If you only care about a particular order (e.g. `Buy` comes first) then you can use a regexp: `Buy.*0.00000057`, as mentioned by @zck. But if you need to check for both orders then *a single regexp won't do the job*.\

To match multiple things in any order, here are two approaches.

- Use `occur`, refining its output with multiple patterns.

  1. Use `M-x occur Buy` to get matches for `Buy` in buffer `*Occur*`.
  2. Use `C-x C-q` in buffer `*Occur*`, to make it modifiable.
  3. With the cursor at the top of `*Occur*` (`M-<`), use `M-x keep-lines 0.00000057`, to keep only lines that also match `0.00000057`.

     - This technique works with all kinds of buffers, including `*grep*` output, for instance. Repeat `keep-lines` to match as many patterns as you want.
     - You can also use the dual command `flush-lines`, to *remove* lines that match another regexp. You can use `flush-lines` and `keep-lines` any number of times, to refine matches.
- Alternatively, if you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use any number of patterns together, to match things in any order (for any matching context). Each pattern can be a regexp, literal string, or fuzzy-match pattern.

Comment: "*single regexp won't do*" - Technically, the single regexp `Buy.*0.00000057\|0.00000057.*Buy` should work. Not that I would recommend it though.

Comment: @npostavs: Nor would I. But more important is the general case - any number of things to match, in any order.